# List of NFC (Near-Field Communication) Capable Phones

Tags: mobile, nfc

I was wondering if anybody knew of a list of NFC Capable phones.  I believe certain iPhones and a Nexus phone are capable of NFC.  Are there any more at the current time?  More specifically, does the Droid2 have NFC capabilities?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication#NFC-enabled_handsets

Comment: In three months this question isn't going to be very useful. This is a constantly moving target.

Answer (score 2):

Try this list, updated daily. It's as close to definitive as you'll find:

http://www.nfcworld.com/nfc-phones-list/

(Disclosure: I maintain this list)

Answer (score 1):

There's only one commercially available NFC handset, Samsung's Nexus S on the Android platform. The rest are concept phones that had limited production runs. AFAIK there's no iPhone with an integrated NFC chip, but there is at least one add-on module for the iPhone which adds NFC as external hardware. Rumor has it that the iPhone 5 will have integrated NFC, and I recently heard another rumor that it won't ;)